# Does Google Drive notify when sharing stops?

Tags: google-sheets, notifications, google-drive-sharing

Google Drive will send a notification to somebody when I share a Google Sheet with them. Will it also send a notification when I stop sharing that file with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't send any "end of sharing" notification. (Also, it's not necessary to send any notification when something is shared)